# how to fix Bootstrap-react tooltip blinking scrolled in body?

Tags: tooltip, fixed

I have problem with Bootstrap-react **tooltips** for  tag Tooltips working well when page is scrolled to the top. But whenever i hover the tag open tooltips and blinking scroll down and top.

Here is basic example with mentioned problem

[image: 1]

```
return(
    <>
        <OverlayTrigger
          key={props.toolplace}
          placement={props.toolplace}
          overlay={
            <Tooltip id={`tooltip-${props.toolplace}`}>
              {props.tooltipText}
            </Tooltip>
          }
        >
          {props.children}
        </OverlayTrigger>
    </>
  );
```

> i have to try the solved this problem in `**Position: Fixed **`   then solved my problem

<Tooltip id={`tooltip-${props.toolplace}`} **style={{position:"fixed"}}**>
{props.tooltipText}

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned, adding this to the `Tooltip` tag solved the issue for me:

```
style={{position:"fixed"}}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked. I was able to fix uneasy screen flickering issue.